# VPN over two computers

Tags: vpn, connection

I have two computers with Windows 7 64 bit. The first is a PC and the second is a laptop.

I get my internet connection through a wireless [D-Link DI 154](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=226) router. The Ethernet cable is connected to the router and to the PC; the LAN cable is connected to the router.

How can I create a VPN connection to these two computers?

Comment: `The Ethernet cable is connected to the router and to the PC; the LAN cable is connected to the router.` ?? You just repeated your self using different terms.. draw a sketch and be more specific please.

Comment: As said, draw a diagram of what you want, please.

Comment: I just explain the way of how I share internet to the two computers
The thing wich I want is how to access the two computers with VPN throught the wirelles router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the router's IP address as visible on the WAN/LAN (ppumkin: outside of the setup)
You should create two routings on the router so that connection to one port is mapped to the VPN port on one computer, and another port is mapped to the VPN port on another computer. Then you can VPN to your two computers by specifying the router's IP address and a port number of your choice

Update: [Here](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Dlink/DI-524/BitTorrent.htm) is a guide on how to forward ports for the BitTorrent app. You will have to similarily go to the "Virtual Server" tab and set up port forwarding:
Set up two distinct public ports, so you can connect to two different computers from the outside. As for the private ports, make them match the port used by your VPN application. The private ports can be the same.

Comment: The main problem is that I do not know how to do this. So can you give me some link with example of step by step or something.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jordan, I've updated the post. I hope you'll find that guide helpful